# 400: Problem communicating with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-vector-tile

I have loaded at GeoServer some layers in Mapbox vectortiles. It seems that they show well in the web viewer but there are many errors in the console. If I put the URL in the browser shows "400: Problem communicating with GeoServer" Anyone knows what is the possible problem?